# JSfiddle Lesson - Functions and Operators

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, operators

below is a code from jsfiddles 
http://jsfiddle.net/7n3rtpqo/3/

I am a little confused and do not fully understand the meaning of the operators '+=' and '-='. I would like to request the meaning in layman terms in the questions below.

Question 1 (refer to code //Question 1):
I do not understand this function to check if the train is going at top speed. Can this be explained? The explanation given is if it is greater than 10, then the train can go faster, so the next line subtracts 10 from the value of trainSpeed.

Why is the amount 10 and why subtract?

Question 2 (refer to code //Question 2):
Does this mean the train position is increased by 2px every time from its last updated position?

I am still fresh in learning JavaScript. Therefore, an explanation in layman terms wherever necessary would be nice as I am trying to make sense of it.

Thanks in advance!

```js
var trainSpeed = 250;
var trainPosition = 0;
var animation;

var train = document.getElementById("train");
train.addEventListener("click", speedUp);

var stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopTrain);


//Question 1
function speedUp() {
    if (trainSpeed > 10) {
        trainSpeed -= 10;
    }
    console.log("train speed: " + trainSpeed);

    clearInterval(animation);
    animation = setInterval(frame, trainSpeed);


//Question 2
    function frame() {
        trainPosition += 2;
        train.style.left = trainPosition + 'px';
        console.log(trainPosition);
        checkPosition(trainPosition);
    }
}

function checkPosition(currentPosition) {
    if (currentPosition === 260) {
        alert("Crash!");
        console.log("Crash!");
        clearInterval(animation);
    }
}

function stopTrain() {
    if (trainPosition < 260) {
        clearInterval(animation);
        console.log("Whew! That was close!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is far too broad, as well as covering ground previous questions have already covered. Break up your question into smaller questions ("How do `+=` and `-=` work?"), look for the answers to those questions (you'll find that one), and ask any questions you have left when you've done your research and internalized those previous answers. Also consider working through some basic tutorials first, as SO is not a good place for tutorial-style information.

Comment: @TJCrowder I actually understand how it works. Just needed some clarification as I did not understand how the function in question work (especially Q1) but I got it. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hah. The code is deceptive. The train speed is ***not*** the train speed, it's the ***delay*** between each calculation of the train's position. This is evidenced in the line

```
animation = setInterval(frame, trainSpeed);
```

(The second parameter to `setInterval` determines how often the `frame` function is called, in milliseconds.)

If I was the author of the code, I'd rather rename the variable `trainSpeed` to `trainDelay`.

Comment: I think I finally got what it means from your answer. I viewed the console after playing the animation and this is what I believe it meant:

Initial delay of the train moving between each position is 250ms.
Initial and every subsequent click reduces the delay by 10ms which causes the train move faster. 
If delay reaches 10ms, no further subtraction will be made (meaning train will be at its top speed).

Thanks for this observation.